# Extra line spacing/ padding in my MS Access Report

Tags: ms-access

I've created a report from a query. I have 2 groups: group on InvoiceNumber and group on feeDescripion.

The items are displayed nicely in the first group  but the second group is putting extra padding under of the text boxes: http://prntscr.com/6zust9

I've tried shrinking my text boxes and not allowing them to grow but the phantom spaces keep coming back (grrr) As you can see by the highlighting the text boxes are only 4mm high Access is just chucking an extra 4mm padding between each line any suggestions?

Comment: You should take a print screen of your report in design mode.

Comment: Thanks I figured a work around, by inserting a sub report. I think the problem was caused because my query had some empty fields

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and found the issue when I copied one of the affected fields into Excel to see what I could see.  Turns out the field value had included an Alt-Enter character in the middle of the string (as is common in excel when forcing a new line in a cell).  When I deleted the alt-enter, the problem went away.